# Adding two kets (and Hamiltonians) from two different hilbert spaces?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

The combined wavefunction for kets in two different Hilbert spaces

$$|\psi\rangle= c_{11}|11\rangle + c_{1r}|1r\rangle +c_{r1}|r1\rangle +c_{rr}|rr\rangle$$

Where $|ab\rangle = |a\rangle_1 \otimes |b\rangle_2$, and $|a\rangle$ is in a different Hilbert space than $|b\rangle$.

The Hamiltonian for each Hilbert space is say $$H_1 = H_2 = \left( \begin{matrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{matrix} \right)$$

How would you combine $H_1$ and $H_2$ to produce a Hamiltonian that can act on the above $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: clarification: are $A,B,C,D$ complex numbers? What are the dimensions of the two Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Please take note of the formatting edits I have made for future posts. It looks like you were making things way more complicated than they needed to be. If you have to split up your expressions with many $'s, then there is probably a simpler way :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider that a state ket $\,\boldsymbol{|}\psi_1\boldsymbol{\rangle}\,$ in the 2-dimensional Hilbert space $\,\mathcal{H}_1\,$ is represented by its components with respect to a basis of this space by

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{|}\psi_1\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\xi_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathcal{H}_1
 \tag{01a}\label{01a}
\end{equation}
and the Hamiltonian by the hermitian matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{H}_{1}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_1 & d_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
 \tag{01b}\label{01b}
\end{equation}
Similarly in the two dimensional Hilbert space $\,\mathcal{H}_2\,$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{|}\psi_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\eta_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\eta_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathcal{H}_2
 \tag{02a}\label{02a}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{H}_{2}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_2 & d_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
 \tag{02b}\label{02b}
\end{equation}
One way  to represent the product state $\,\boldsymbol{|}\psi_1\psi_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\boldsymbol{|}\psi_1\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{|}\psi_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}\,$ in the 4-dimensional product Hilbert space $\,\mathcal{H}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\mathcal{H}_1\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathcal{H}_2\,$ is
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{|}\psi_1\psi_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\boldsymbol{|}\psi_1\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{|}\psi_2\boldsymbol{\rangle}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\xi_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\otimes}
\begin{bmatrix}
\eta_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\eta_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_1 \begin{bmatrix}
\eta_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\eta_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\xi_2 \begin{bmatrix}
\eta_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\eta_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_1\eta_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\xi_1\eta_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\xi_2\eta_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
\xi_2\eta_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathcal{H}
 \tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}
Motivated by the following  ZeroTheHero's comment

[image]

the Hamiltonian in the product space is
\begin{equation}
  \mathsf{H}\equiv \mathsf{H}_{1}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\,\mathsf{I}_{2}\boldsymbol{+}\mathsf{I}_{1}\,\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathsf{H}_{2}
\tag{04}\label{04}    
\end{equation}

Under the convention \eqref{03}
\begin{align}
 \mathsf{H}_{1}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\,\mathsf{I}_{2}
 &\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_1 & d_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\otimes}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\hphantom{_1} & 0\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
0\hphantom{_1} & 1\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\begin{bmatrix}
1\hphantom{_1} & 0\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
0\hphantom{_1} & 1\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}  & b_1\begin{bmatrix}
1\hphantom{_1} & 0\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
0\hphantom{_1} & 1\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} \\
c_1\begin{bmatrix}
1\hphantom{_1} & 0\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
0\hphantom{_1} & 1\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}  & d_1\begin{bmatrix}
1\hphantom{_1} & 0\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
0\hphantom{_1} & 1\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & b_1 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & a_1 & 0 & b_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c_1 & 0 & d_1 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & c_1 & 0 & d_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{05a}\label{05a}    
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
 \mathsf{I}_{1}\,\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathsf{H}_{2}
&\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\hphantom{_1} & 0\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
0\hphantom{_1} & 1\hphantom{_1}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{\otimes}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_2 & d_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_2 & d_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}  & 0 \begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_2 & d_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} \\
0\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_2 & d_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}  & 1 \begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} \\
c_2 & d_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & b_2 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c_2 & d_2 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & 0 & a_2 & b_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & 0 & c_2 & d_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{05b}\label{05b}    
\end{align}
Adding \eqref{05a},\eqref{05b} 
\begin{equation}
  \mathsf{H}\equiv \mathsf{H}_{1}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\,\mathsf{I}_{2}\boldsymbol{+}\mathsf{I}_{1}\,\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathsf{H}_{2}
  \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\boldsymbol{+}a_2 & b_2 & b_1 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c_2 & a_1\boldsymbol{+}d_2 & 0 & b_1 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c_1 & 0 & d_1\boldsymbol{+}a_2 & b_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & c_1 & c_2 & d_1\boldsymbol{+}d_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{06}\label{06}    
\end{equation}
Note that if in both spaces we make use of the basis of eigenkets of the respective Hamiltonian for the matrix representations then, since $\,c_1\boldsymbol{=}0\boldsymbol{=}b_1\,$, the eigenvalues of $\,\mathsf{H}_{1}\,$ are $\,a_1,d_1\,$ and since $\,c_2\boldsymbol{=}0\boldsymbol{=}b_2\,$ the eigenvalues of $\,\mathsf{H}_{2}\,$ are $\,a_2,d_2\,$ while from \eqref{06}
\begin{equation}
  \mathsf{H}\equiv \mathsf{H}_{1}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\,\mathsf{I}_{2}\boldsymbol{+}\mathsf{I}_{1}\,\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathsf{H}_{2}
  \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\boldsymbol{+}a_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & a_1\boldsymbol{+}d_2 & 0 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & 0 & d_1\boldsymbol{+}a_2 & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d_1\boldsymbol{+}d_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{07}\label{07}    
\end{equation}
that is the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian  in the product space are sums produced by   combinations of the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonians in the factor spaces.